# Pandas - iloc - comparing value to the cell below

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, calculated-columns

For the following table:

[image]

Using Pandas - I would like achieve the desired_output column, that is TRUE when the value below the current cell i different - otherwise FALSE.

I have tried the following code - but error occurs.

```
df['desired_output']=df.two.apply(lambda x: True if df.iloc[int(x),1]==df.iloc[int(x+1),1] else False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df['desired_output'] = df['city'].shift().bfill() != df['city']
```

Comment: The edit is also interesting, seems like I should carefully read the pandas docu again.

Answer (score 3):

Compare by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values and first missing value is replaced by original value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'city':list('mmmssb')})

df['out'] = df['city'].ne(df['city'].shift(fill_value=df['city'].iat[0]))
print (df)
  city    out
0    m  False
1    m  False
2    m  False
3    s   True
4    s  False
5    b   True
```

For oldier pandas versions if no missing values in column `city` is used replace first missing value by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['out'] = df['city'].ne(df['city'].shift().fillna(df['city']))
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of .ne() nice.

Comment: @AngusStevenson - yop, so no missing values in data?